# PHP file_get_contents get all city names by country name

Tags: php, file-get-contents, wiki

I trying to figure whole night how to get all this city names and put it in my database... I used a wiki page for countries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_cities_by_country and i solve that problem and added something like 200 countries to my database... Now the real problem is with cities i used a file_get_contents and i finished adding countries now my problem is with cities.. I tryed alot of examples but i didnt find solution... I just need to get simple list without html or nothnig of city names (list)... So i can insert them in database one by one...
If someone already worked with this i will be thankfull 4 help :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Afghanistan

Comment: Wikipedia is certainly not the best source for this information. I googled and found this: [World Cities Database](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities) and [Major cities of the world](https://datahub.io/core/world-cities) and many more. It seems much easier to use a simple CSV file.

Comment: Yes i searched all that websites but i didnt find solution, cuz i added countries i need to add a cities its was alot of job so i didnt added custom one by one and i used wiki countries list and added success.. Now i just need to get cities for all that countries cuz it will take a eternal to add countries + cities custom in acp :D I just need simple list with their names for specific country so i put a wikipedia url up like example of Afghanistan...

Comment: I tried the first link I gave you, it contains 12893 cities with country names. I don't see the problem?

Comment: Its problem cuz i used wiki for locations, so if i get this first table on country page and first td without html or links i can put them in query so i can add for all countries  all cities in one time if u understand me.. I just need via file_get_contents to get this first table but only a city name and then to put them in database :)

Comment: It can't be easily done because the cities names pages in Wikipedia are all different. This whole approach is flawed. Do **not** try to do this, you'll waste more of your time.

Comment: I dont have alot of choise to adding them custom one by one in acp or to fetch them all, i just cant get this first table and just a names of cities and not other data.. If there is someone who can make me just a simple list with file_get_contents of this example link i give in first post without html or links... Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try Using "[Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)".